# *Not* getting ChangeConflictException using Devart

Tags: c#, linq, concurrency, devart

I'm investigating an intermittent occurrence of `Devart.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed`.

I've been reading the Devart article on [concurrency conflicts](https://www.devart.com/linqconnect/docs/ChangeConflictException.html), and just as a starting point I am trying to reproduce a concurrency conflict.  Using the included MS-based LINQ classes this is easy to do (using the code structure below does so successfully).  However even following their example in the article I can't produce an exception.  I have tried

- Using both an ADO paramaterised query exactly as shown in their article
- Using the simplified ADO query shown below (not worried about injection attacks during this test)
- Using LinqConnect with a new context (also suggested in their article).
- Pausing execution with a debugger and manually updating table using MySQL Workbench.

This is the test code I am using:

```
public static void MySqlTest()
{
    using (MySqlDataContext db = new MySqlDataContext())
    {
        Customer customer = db.Customers.First(c => c.Username.Equals("ian2"));

        MySqlAdoChange(db.Connection);
        //MySqlLinqConnectChange();

        customer.Address1 = "Original change" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}

public static void MySqlAdoChange(DbConnection connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE customers SET Address1 = 'Conflicting change" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks + "' WHERE Username = 'ian2'";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

public static void MySqlLinqConnectChange()
{
    using (MySqlDataContext db = new MySqlDataContext())
    {
        Customer customer = db.Customers.First(c => c.Username.Equals("ian2"));
        customer.Address1 = "Conflicting change" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

<s>What is doubly-strange is that the value saved to the database *alternates* between the two!</s>
  *I had to append DateTime ticks on to the end to ensure uniqueness, otherwise it was optimising away my update, and only updating to become the value that wasn't currently active.*

Can anyone explain this behaviour?  Why can't I produce a ChangeConflictException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that in your example code, you update `Phone` field in `MySqlTest` function, but `Address1` field in `MySqlAdoChange` function, so there cannot be any conflict.

However, most likely even if you correct this you won't have update conflict anyway. If you look at your `Customer` class source code, at `Phone` property, you (most likely) will see it is decorated with Column attribute with `UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never` (which is the default: see here https://www.devart.com/linqconnect/docs/MemberMapping.html). So by default, LinqConnect won't check for update conflicts for your fields, unless you tell it which fields to check by decorating them with `UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Always` or `UpdateCheck.WhenChanged`. Of course you should not modify source code directly but instead change that property in model designer.

Comment: You're right of course about the Phone vs Address.  Originally I was testing on the Phone field (which is actually a text field, but not obviously so), then I decided to use Address to "simplify" things, and didn't update the SO question correctly.  I will look into the attribute you suggest, thanks for the info.  I have another bounty question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586779/devart-changeconflictexception-but-values-still-written-to-database?lq=1) which you might be interested in, this one is just a subset of the larger problem.

Comment: You were spot-on twice, my variables were _all_ (barring ID PKs) decorated with `UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never` attribute.  And removing it generates an exception as expected.  Thank you very much, that solves half my problem.  But it now makes my other `ChangeConflictException` issue even more puzzling.